# SQLAlchemy inheritance from non-orm class

Tags: python, inheritance, orm, sqlalchemy, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to develop a ORM-version of my non-ORM class to be able to store the object in a database (and retrieve it back, if possible).

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAMLObject

class User(YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'user'

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    # Other useful methods
```

What I would like to achieve now is a similar object, that acts like `User` in the Python world, but that can be used also as an ORM object, hence being able to store it in a database. What I tried, ingenuously, is:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class SQLUser(Base, User):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Running an example with this class hierarchy produces, on Python 2, the following error:

> **TypeError**: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

I believe this is related to `YAMLObject` metaclass... But I need it since I would like also to be able to save those objects as YAML. For what I read about this error I should, maybe, use a third metaclass that inherits both from `YAMLObject` metaclass and `Base`, then using it to create the class I want...

```
class MetaMixinUser(type(User), type(Base)):
    pass

class SQLUser(six.with_metaclass(MetaMixinUser)):
    #[...]
```

Unfortunately this gives another error:

> **AttributeError**: type object 'SQLUser' has no attribute '_decl_class_registry'

Could you please point me where my reasoning is flawing?

Comment: You don't have to inherit from `YAMLObject` to be able to dump `User`. Subclassing is IMO the most intrusive way of enabling dumping and loading. And your `User` class probably doesn't work because it doesn't have a `yaml_tag`. Are you open to removing the dependency on `YAMLObject`?

Comment: @Anthon Sorry, I omitted the `yaml_tag` but it's there. I edited my question. The `User` class works correctly by itself (I implemented the `to_yaml` method to enable the class to be dumped correctly into YAML files). I'm open to everything, but in this way I can dump the object as I wish in a transparent way to the end-user. Just a `yaml.dump` works as expected...

Comment: I added [registering and decorating functionality to `ruamel.yaml`](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html). I am not sure which of the solutions in my answer you actually used, but registering should work for you, decorating might still interfere because of the wrapping that it does.

Comment: @Anthon I used the decorator as you suggested and the inheritance was working as expected  in the brief tests I did. Thanks for you help and support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a hurry: as of `ruamel.yaml` 0.15.19 you can [register classes](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html) with one statement, without subclassing of `YAMLObject`:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.register_class(User)
```

---

The `YAMLObject` is there for backwards compatibility with PyYAML, and although it might be convenient, I cannot really recommend using it for three reasons:

1. It makes your class hierarchy dependent on `YAMLObject`, which, as you noticed, can interfere with other dependencies
2. It uses the unsafe `Loader` by default
3. A solution based on Python decorators would be as convenient and much less intrusive.

The only real thing that subclassing `YAMLObject` does is registering a `constructor` for that `yaml_tag` and a `representer` for subclass.

All examples assume  `from __future__ import print_function` if you run Python 2.

If you have the following, based on subclassing `YAMLObject`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.std.pathlib import Path

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='unsafe')

class User(ruamel.yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'user'

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, 
                                            u'{.name}-{.age}'.format(node, node))

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        # type: (Any, Any) -> Any
        return User(*node.value.split('-'))


data = {'users': [User('Anthon', 18)]}
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print()
tmp_file = Path('tmp.yaml')
yaml.dump(data, tmp_file)
rd = yaml.load(tmp_file)
print(rd['users'][0].name, rd['users'][0].age)
```

that will get you:

```
users: [!<user> Anthon-18]

Anthon 18
```

You can get the exact same result without subclassing, by doing:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.std.pathlib import Path

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

class User(object):
    yaml_tag = u'user'

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, 
                                            u'{.name}-{.age}'.format(node, node))

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        # type: (Any, Any) -> Any
        return User(*node.value.split('-'))


yaml.representer.add_representer(User, User.to_yaml)
yaml.constructor.add_constructor(User.yaml_tag, User.from_yaml)

data = {'users': [User('Anthon', 18)]}

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print()
tmp_file = Path('tmp.yaml')
yaml.dump(data, tmp_file)
rd = yaml.load(tmp_file)
print(rd['users'][0].name, rd['users'][0].age)
```

The above uses the `SafeLoader` (and `SafeDumper`), which is a step in the right direction. But adding the `XXXX.add_YYY` lines above is nuisance if you have a lot of classes, as those entries are almost, but not quite, the same. And it doesn't handle classes missing either or both `to_yaml` and `from_yaml`.

To solve the above I suggest you make a decorator `yaml_object` and a helper class in a file `myyaml.py`:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

class SafeYAMLObject(object):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._cls = cls

    def to_yaml(self, representer, data):
        return representer.represent_yaml_object(
            self._cls.yaml_tag, data, self._cls,
            flow_style=representer.default_flow_style)

    def from_yaml(self, constructor, node):
        return constructor.construct_yaml_object(node, self._cls)

def yaml_object(cls):
    yaml.representer.add_representer(
        cls, getattr(cls, 'to_yaml', SafeYAMLObject(cls).to_yaml))
    yaml.constructor.add_constructor(
        cls.yaml_tag, getattr(cls, 'from_yaml', SafeYAMLObject(cls).from_yaml))
    return cls
```

Having that you can do:

```
import sys
from ruamel.std.pathlib import Path
from myyaml import yaml, yaml_object

@yaml_object
class User(object):
    yaml_tag = u'user'

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(cls.yaml_tag, 
                                            u'{.name}-{.age}'.format(node, node))

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        # type: (Any, Any) -> Any
        return User(*node.value.split('-'))


data = {'users': [User('Anthon', 18)]}

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print()
tmp_file = Path('tmp.yaml')
yaml.dump(data, tmp_file)
rd = yaml.load(tmp_file)
print(rd['users'][0].name, rd['users'][0].age)
```

again with the same result. If you remove the `to_yaml` and `from_yaml` methods, you would the same final value, but slightly different YAML:

```
users:
- !<user> {age: 18, name: Anthon}

Anthon 18
```

I have not been able to test this, but using this decorator instead of subclassing `YAMLObject` should get rid of the `TypeError` when doing:

```
class SQLUser(Base, User):
```

---

¹ 
<sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of the `ruamel.yaml` package used in this answer.

   Disclaimer 2: I am not really 18, but I do follow Brian Adams' adagium expressed in the title song of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18_til_I_Die) album</sub>